# Displaying text as soon as a radio button is clicked, dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of radio buttons. They each correspond to a number from 1 - 24. I want to display that number somewhere else in the page as soon as a radio button is selected. How would I do this?

Comment: please post html or link to example page

Comment: Are you okay with a jQuery solution, or are you looking for a library-free answer?

Comment: Are you ok with a javascript solution, or are you looking for a jQuery solution?

Comment: jQuery all the way. No need for library-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a DIV with the ID "displayNum", with "display:none" style property

Then you create an "onClick" handler to the radio buttons.

The function called from the handler would figure out which button was clicked (from the button's ID) and then change the content of the "displayNum" DIV to the number (using innerHtml property of the DIV), as well as change the "display" property of the DIV from invisible "none" to visible "block".

Comment: If I want the displayNum inside a `<input="text" value="numberhere">` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<div id="someplace"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateText(number) {
        document.getElementById("someplace").innerHTML = number;
    }
</script>
<input value="1" type="radio" onclick="updateText(1)"/>1<br/>
<input value="2" type="radio" onclick="updateText(2)"/>2<br/>
...
```

If you want to do something more advanced, like not have to put (1) and (2) in each onclick, use something more advanced [Jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Is the `click` event also fired when I navigate to another radio button with my keyboard?

Comment: is the `id="someplace"` how to put in a `<input="text">`?